# Sprite kit countdown SKLabel

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

Good day!
i want to make a timer with SKLabel that count back time in milliseconds. but i did only in seconds like this:

```
SKLabelNode *countDown = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
countDown.position = CGPointMake(10, -20);
countDown.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
countDown.fontSize = 20;
[bonus_10 addChild: countDown];
// Initialize the countdown variable
__block float countDownInt = i;
// Define the actions
SKAction *updateLabel = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", countDownInt];
    countDownInt = countDownInt-0.1;
}];
// Create a combined action
SKAction *updateLabelAndWait = [SKAction sequence:@[updateLabel, wait]];
// Run action "seconds" number of times and then set the label to indicate
// the countdown has ended
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatAction] completion:^{
    countDown.text = @"Time's Up";
}];
```

is there any opportunity to do timer in milliseconds? thanks!

Comment: i have this code all written out in swift if you dont mind converting it over

Comment: if you post the code, i'll try to convert it

Answer (score 2):

If it is OK for you to skip the showing of some milliseconds, I would use the update method.

Something like this:

```
var dt: NSTimeInterval = 0
var lastUpdateTime: NSTimeInterval = 0

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    } else {
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    countDownInt = countDownInt-dt
    countDown.text = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you put seconds in here as a decimal (like from update) it will format it as

minutes:seconds:deciseconds

```
func timeString(seconds : CGFloat) -> String {

    // 90 seconds = 1.5
    let minutesFloat = seconds / 60

    // 1.5 = 1
    let minutes = floor(minutesFloat)

    // (1.5 - 1) * 60 = 30.01
    let secondsFloat = (minutesFloat - minutes) * 60

    // 30.01 = 30
    let secs = floor(secondsFloat)

    // (30.01 - 30) * 100 = 1.0
    let secsDec = floor((secondsFloat - secs) * 100)

    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", Int(minutes), Int(secs), Int(secsDec))
}
```